# No module named 'win32api' error when I run my code

Tags: python

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEjvb.png)

[This is the error I get when I try downloading win32api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCLXd.png)

I already have pywin32 downloaded, and when I go to run my code I get the "no module named win32api error".

Comment: nvm i literally just restarted my python and it picked it up

Comment: Delete your question then please

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to install with pip at moment due to version mismatch. try installing with this link.
[enter link description here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/)